# Python Selenium download button click

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web

I'm trying to download some reports from [amex](https://www.americanexpress.com/en-us/business/merchant/payments/transactions)  site.
[site screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJpg3.png)
[image: menu screenshot]

I faced a problem that the download button is not visible/clickable for the selenium.

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (888, 869)

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window()

browser.get('https://merchant-global.americanexpress.com/login?TARGET=https%3A%2F%2Fmerchants-r1.americanexpress.com'
            '%2Fen-us%2Fbusiness%2Fmerchant%2Fpayments%2Ftransactions')

browser.find_element(By.ID, 'user_id').send_keys('')
browser.find_element(By.ID, 'password').send_keys('')
browser.find_element(By.ID, 'password').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "open-download-flyout-transactions"))).click()
#WebDriverWait(browser, 4).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="filter-container-download-filter-transactions"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(browser, 4).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'searchTransactions-download-apply-button'))).click()
#element = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'searchTransactions-download-apply-button')
time.sleep(5)
```

[image: Element description]

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try in this situation is to use javascript to click the element.

```
element_to_click = WebDriverWait(browser, 4).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'searchTransactions-download-apply-button')))

browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element_to_click)
```